# Fix for Enabled changing button "Down" status

Tags: delphi, button, delphi-5

I have some TSpeedButtons on a form that has multiple uses. In one mode I don't want one button to be clicked so I just set "Enabled:=False;"

But, if it **was Down** and I force it to Enabled:=False it goes to the Up-State. How can I prevent "Enabled" affecting the current Up/Down State as I still need it to visually show the current State.

Comment: I don't have delphi 5 but in XE8 Changing enabled doesn't have any effect on the Down.

Answer (score 4):

In short, you cannot do what you are asking for with a standard `TSpeedButton`.  This is just the way it is coded to work.

When you set `Enabled` to false on a `TSpeedButton`, the button gets drawn in a disabled state regardless of its `Down` property.  The `TSpeedButton.Paint()` method forces the `State` property to `bsDisabled`, wiping out any current Up/Down state.  In Delphi 5, this causes the button to be drawn with an Up appearance.  In more modern versions of Delphi, if visual styles are enabled, the button gets drawn with a flat appearance that is neither Up nor Down.

The only way to change this behavior is to either:

1. derive a new class from `TSpeedButton` and override the virtual `Paint()` method so you can custom-draw the button yourself however you want.  You will have to draw the *entire* button, though.
2. make a copy of the VCL's `Buttons.pas` source file (`Vcl.Buttons.pas` in XE2 and later), add the copied file to your project (make sure Runtime Packages are disabled), and then you can modify the `implementation` of `TSpeedButton.Paint()` itself however you want.  Just know that this will affect every `TSpeedButton` in your project.

Comment: Thanks, just one more question, how does one go about getting the source to XE2? Surely I don't need to buy XE2? :) I actually worked around it by putting the button on a slightly larger Panel and I disable the Panel. The Panel Color is changed to red when disabled so there is s 2-Pixel wide line around the button to indicate it is Visual-only.

Comment: Yes, you need to buy XE2 to get XE2'S VCL source code. Or any other version, for that matter.